# Sort graph data into columns

Tags: javascript, graph

I have this data:

```
const main = 'a';
const data = [{
  from: 'a',
  to: 'b'
}, {
  from: 'b',
  to: 'c'
}, {
  from: 'c',
  to: 'd'
}, {
  from: 'b',
  to: 'd'
},
 {
   from: 'd',
   to: 'e'
 },
  {
    from: 'a',
    to: 'e'
  }
];
```

i want to format it so it turns out to be something like:

```
{
  col1: [b, ""],
  col2: [c, "", ""],
  col3: [d, ""],
  col4: [e]
}
```

This layout will be used to place the nodes to their positions.

The graph should look like (sorry for my bad paint skills):

[image]

The empty strings represent 'invisible nodes' that i will use to connect other nodes with paths. The graph will have fixed node positions.

How can i achieve the format above? Thanks

Comment: I dont think this data structure makes much sense. Like these columns are applicable only if you know some order (right now i.e. alphabetical). Maybe you can explain more what is your use-case and what are you trying to achieve (there can be issue just in gathering proper requirment and solution)

Comment: I guess you could somehow [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the array (e.g., remember you current node and process the edge if it goes off the current node and then set the new node ...)

Comment: @JSHelp do you have an example of how you would achieve that in this case?

Comment: How do you represent the connection between nodes? What happen if I remove the connection A -> B -> C? I can make a function to return exactly the example you're looking for but it will just work if all the nodes are connected alphabetically...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick sample solution.

- Assumption: the order of the node (`from` and `to`) follows the order of encountering them in `data`
- Caveat: this is of the order of `O(m * n)`

  ```
  const main = 'a';
  const data = [...];

  let order = [];
  let res = {};

  data.forEach(i => {
      if (!order.includes(i.from)) {
          order.push(i.from);
          res[i.from] = 0;
      }
      if (!order.includes(i.to)) {
          order.push(i.to);
          res[i.to] = 0;
      }
      for (let temp = order.indexOf(i.from) + 1; temp < order.indexOf(i.to); temp++)
          res[order[temp]]++;
  });
  ```

You can delete `a` from `res`, change the data structure as you like, and so on.